# Crosshair causing crash (Shinobicontrols Chart) - 'CALayerInvalidGeometry'

Tags: ios, charts, shinobi

I am getting crash when using Crosshair enable. I have tried a lot to find out the solution but failed. Please see issue the below.

The Issue is: The chart is creating fine. But If I use the below lines for crosshair enable, mainly the second line below then I am getting crash. Initially it is fine, when I am tapping and drag it for move then App crashing.

```
lineSeries.style.pointStyle.showPoints = YES;

lineSeries.crosshairEnabled = YES;

lineSeries.selectionMode = SChartSelectionPoint;
```

Crash message:

```
reason: 'CALayer position contains NaN: [559 nan]'
```

Answer (score 0):

**Disclaimer**: I work for ShinobiControls.

After some investigation we found this to be an issue with our crosshair's interpolation code that positions the crosshair between two datapoints.

A work around solution to prevent this crash would be to turn off point interpolation on your crosshair by using the following code:

`chart.crosshair.interpolatePoints = NO;`

This issue has been added to our backlog and a member of our team will update this answer when the fix for this issue has been released.

**Update**: ShinobiCharts version 2.8.0 contains a fix for this problem - I hope that helps!